# Is there any good way to optimize the speed of this python code?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, numba

I have a following piece of code, which basically evaluates some numerical expression, and use it to integrate over certain range of values. The current piece of code runs within about `8.6 s`, but I am just using mock values, and my actual array is much larger. Especially, my actual size of `freq_c= (3800, 101)` and size of `number_bin = (3800, 100)`, which makes the following code really inefficient, as the total execution time will be close to 9 minutes for the actual array. One part of the code that is quite slow is evaluation of `k_one_third` and `k_two_third`, for which I have also used `numexpr.evaluate("..")`, which speeds up the code quite a bit by about 10-20%. But, I have avoided `numexpr` below, so that anyone can run it without having to install the package. Is there any more ways to improve the speed of this code? An improvement of a few factor would also be good enough. Please note that the `for loop` is almost unavoidable, due to memory issues, as the arrays are really large, I am manipulating each axis at a time through the loop. I also wonder if `numba jit` optimisation is possible here.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 
from scipy.integrate import simps as simps
import time

def k_one_third(x):
    return (2.*np.exp(-x**2)/x**(1/3) + 4./x**(1/6)*np.exp(-x)/(1+x**(1/3)))**2

def k_two_third(x):
    return (np.exp(-x**2)/x**(2/3) + 2.*x**(5/2)*np.exp(-x)/(6.+x**3))**2

def spectrum(freq_c, number_bin, frequency, gamma, theta):
    theta_gamma_factor = np.einsum('i,j->ij', theta**2, gamma**2)
    theta_gamma_factor += 1.
    t_g_bessel_factor = 1.-1./theta_gamma_factor
    number = np.concatenate((number_bin, np.zeros((number_bin.shape[0], 1), dtype=number_bin.dtype)), axis=1)
    number_theta_gamma = np.einsum('jk, ik->ijk', theta_gamma_factor**2*1./gamma**3, number)
    final = np.zeros((np.size(freq_c[:,0]), np.size(theta), np.size(frequency)))
    for i in xrange(np.size(frequency)):
        b_n_omega_theta_gamma = frequency[i]**2*number_theta_gamma
        eta = theta_gamma_factor**(1.5)*frequency[i]/2.
        eta = np.einsum('jk, ik->ijk', eta, 1./freq_c)
        bessel_eta = np.einsum('jl, ijl->ijl',t_g_bessel_factor, k_one_third(eta))
        bessel_eta += k_two_third(eta)
        eta = None
        integrand = np.multiply(bessel_eta, b_n_omega_theta_gamma, out= bessel_eta)
        final[:,:, i] = simps(integrand, gamma)
        integrand = None
    return final

frequency = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
theta = np.linspace(1, 3, 100)
gamma = np.linspace(2, 200, 101)
freq_c = np.random.randint(1, 200, size=(50, 101))
number_bin = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(50, 100))
time1 = time.time()
spectra = spectrum(freq_c, number_bin, frequency, gamma, theta)
print(time.time()-time1)
```

Comment: instead of for loop, you can do numpy operations on the array's. that would save some time

Comment: @Kalyan I was explicitly using loops, because my array is too large to do numpy operations all at once without getting `MemoryError`.

Comment: Rewrite at least your inner loopbody to simple loops (no np.einsums, no multiply and if possible no temporary arrays). This will be much easier to optimise for a compiler like Numba and Cython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments large parts of the code should be rewritten to get best performance.

I have only modified the simpson integration and modified @HYRY answer a bit. This speeds up the calculation from **26.15s** to **1.76s** (15x), by the test-data you provided. By replacing the np.einsums with simple loops this should end up in less than a second. (About 0.4s from the improved integration, 24s from `k_one_two_third(x)`)

For getting performance using Numba [read](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html). The latest Numba version (0.39), the Intel SVML-package and things like fastmath=True makes quite a big impact on your example.

**Code**

```
#a bit faster than HYRY's version
@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True,error_model='numpy')
def k_one_two_third(x):
  one=np.empty(x.shape,dtype=x.dtype)
  two=np.empty(x.shape,dtype=x.dtype)
  for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
      for k in range(x.shape[2]):
        x0 = x[i,j,k] ** (1/3)
        x1 = np.exp(-x[i,j,k] ** 2)
        x2 = np.exp(-x[i,j,k])
        one[i,j,k] = (2*x1/x0 + 4*x2/(x[i,j,k]**(1/6)*(x0 + 1)))**2
        two[i,j,k] = (2*x[i,j,k]**(5/2)*x2/(x[i,j,k]**3 + 6) + x1/x[i,j,k]**(2/3))**2
  return one, two

#improved integration
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def simpson_nb(y_in,dx):
  s = y[0]+y[-1]

  n=y.shape[0]//2
  for i in range(n-1):
    s += 4.*y[i*2+1]
    s += 2.*y[i*2+2]

  s += 4*y[(n-1)*2+1]
  return(dx/ 3.)*s

@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def spectrum(freq_c, number_bin, frequency, gamma, theta):
    theta_gamma_factor = np.einsum('i,j->ij', theta**2, gamma**2)
    theta_gamma_factor += 1.
    t_g_bessel_factor = 1.-1./theta_gamma_factor
    number = np.concatenate((number_bin, np.zeros((number_bin.shape[0], 1), dtype=number_bin.dtype)), axis=1)
    number_theta_gamma = np.einsum('jk, ik->ijk', theta_gamma_factor**2*1./gamma**3, number)
    final = np.empty((np.size(frequency),np.size(freq_c[:,0]), np.size(theta)))

    #assume that dx is const. on integration
    #speedimprovement of the scipy.simps is about 4x
    #numba version to scipy.simps(y,x) is about 60x
    dx=gamma[1]-gamma[0]

    for i in range(np.size(frequency)):
        b_n_omega_theta_gamma = frequency[i]**2*number_theta_gamma
        eta = theta_gamma_factor**(1.5)*frequency[i]/2.
        eta = np.einsum('jk, ik->ijk', eta, 1./freq_c)

        one,two=k_one_two_third(eta)

        bessel_eta = np.einsum('jl, ijl->ijl',t_g_bessel_factor, one)
        bessel_eta += two

        integrand = np.multiply(bessel_eta, b_n_omega_theta_gamma, out= bessel_eta)

        #reorder array
        for j in range(integrand.shape[0]):
          for k in range(integrand.shape[1]):
            final[i,j, k] = simpson_nb(integrand[j,k,:],dx)
    return final
```

Comment: The code looks nice, but I can't execute it. Replacing `njit` with `jit` I get: `NameError: global name 'y' is not defined`. Using `njit` yields: `TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'object'>`. The error stems from the `njit` of `simpson_nb()`.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in the line def simpson_nb(y_in,dx). This should be def simpson_nb(y,dx). I hope this has no impact on performance, I obviously had an array y in my global namespace when testing....

Comment: I corrected the error and now it is working. It is about 20% faster than HYRY's solution. Nice! I guess rewriting it not using `np.einsum` will make it even faster.

Answer (score 5):

I profiled the code and found that `k_one_third()` and `k_two_third()` are slow. There are some duplicated calculations in the two functions.

By merging the two functions into one function, and decorate it with `@numba.jit(parallel=True)`, I got 4x speedup.

```
@jit(parallel=True)
def k_one_two_third(x):
    x0 = x ** (1/3)
    x1 = np.exp(-x ** 2)
    x2 = np.exp(-x)
    one = (2*x1/x0 + 4*x2/(x**(1/6)*(x0 + 1)))**2
    two = (2*x**(5/2)*x2/(x**3 + 6) + x1/x**(2/3))**2
    return one, two
```

Comment: I calculated the same expression with `numexpr` and the speed is faster than using `jit`. So, still no overall boost for me.

Comment: Would `interpolation` speed up this calculation?

Comment: Don't use `parallel=True` in general. This is still experimental and might slow down the calculation on some computers. Try it with `@njit` or `@jit(nopython=True)`. The solution provided by HYRY should be way faster than using `numexpr`.

Comment: @Scotty1 Better would be to introduce fastmath=True and error_model='numpy' with Intel SVML installed. But usually it is recommendable to use explicit parallelization on the outer loop, which is also about 20% faster than the vectorized approach.