# How to make for loop faster with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If inputed an numpy 2d array such as

```
                           100   100   100   100   100
                           100    0     0     0    100
                           100    0     0     0    100
                           100    0     0     0    100
                           100   100   100   100   100
```

an output like this should be obtained

```
                            100   100   100   100   100
                            100    50    25    50   100
                            100    25     0    25   100
                            100    50    25    50   100
                            100   100   100   100   100
```

where every number except the border becomes the mean of its adjacent numbers.

My current code works but I need to use it without for loops and vectorize it using numpy.

My current code:

```
import numpy as np
def evolve_heat_slow(u):      
    u2 = np.copy(u)
    x=u2.shape[0]
    y=u2.shape[1]
    for i in range(1,x-1):
        for s in range(1,y-1):
            u2[i,s]=(u[i-1,s]+u[i+1,s]+u[i,s+1]+u[i,s-1])/4
    return u2
```

Comment: If you have such types of code, you can compile and in your case multithread it using Numba. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50470995/4045774 This often outperforms vectorized solutions, except BLAS calls (eg. np.dot,..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not better than other methods, but you can also use `np.roll` in each direction to do the same thing:

```
def evolve_heat_slow(u):
    u2 = u.copy()
    u2[1:-1, 1:-1] = ((np.roll(u2,1,0) + np.roll(u2,-1,0) 
                        + np.roll(u2,1,1) + np.roll(u2,-1,1))/4)[1:-1, 1:-1]
    return u2
```

now with `u2 = evolve_heat_slow(u)` you get

```
u2 =
array([[100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
       [100,  50,  25,  50, 100],
       [100,  25,   0,  25, 100],
       [100,  50,  25,  50, 100],
       [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])
```

Comment: @akhilrastogi Your dislike for Amadan's answer is really odd to me. This answer is 7 times slower than Amadan's for me on your example array and more than an order of magnitude slower on larger arrays.

Comment: @akhilrastogi Is this 122 times faster?

Answer (score 6):

That's pretty much the definition of 2D convolution. `scipy` has you covered. I copy `a` to preserve the borders; the convolution in `valid` mode will make a smaller array (without the borders), which I then paste inside the prepared "frame".

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

a = np.array([[100, 100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 0, 0, 0, 100],  [100, 0, 0, 0, 100], [100, 0, 0, 0, 100], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])
b = np.array([[0, 0.25, 0], [0.25, 0, 0.25], [0, 0.25, 0]])
r = np.copy(a)
r[1:-1, 1:-1] = convolve2d(a, b, mode='valid')
r
# => array([[100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
#           [100,  50,  25,  50, 100],
#           [100,  25,   0,  25, 100],
#           [100,  50,  25,  50, 100],
#           [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])
```

Comment: i don't understand how this works since every number should be the mean of its adjacent numbers instead of just inputting the value also if one was to put this in a definition with only the input of the original numpy array it wont work.

Comment: The `b` array does it. Convolving with `b` says: "For each element, multiply the element directly above by 0.25, element directly left by 0.25, element directly right by 0.25, element directly below by 0.25, then sum them." Which is basically the same as your `(u[i-1,s]+u[i+1,s]+u[i,s+1]+u[i,s-1])/4`. It's not "inputting values" - `b` is the equivalent of your averaging formula. Think of it as code, not as data.

Comment: yeah but this method is slower than mine so is there anything faster using only numpy without importing anything else

Comment: Maybe. Your code is probably faster for small arrays. But mine _is_ vectorised, and it _is_ without loops, which is what the question asked for. (Counting import in benchmark is not really a fair assessment.) If you want something without importing, you can, I assume, copy-paste `convolve2d` and any necessary support functions out of `scipy`.

Comment: but i need a code with only python numpy functions instead of imports cause it slows down the code

Comment: Really...? `import` slows code down *once*, for a second or so. Then you can go on multiplying things for hours or days afterwards. Why is that one second relevant?

Comment: the code which i am looking for should be 122 times faster

Comment: Faster than what? How are you measuring it? (If you're doing `time python test.py`, it is the entirely wrong way to do it). Why 122? Also, if `scipy` is not fast enough for you, you should move it to C or Fortran, as this is probably the fastest way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Although Amadan's scipy answer makes the most sense for this case, here's another approach doing it "manually":

```
import numpy as np

# Create your array
data = np.ones((5,5)) * 100
data[1:-1,1:-1] = 0

def evolve_heat_slow(m, should_copy=True):
    if should_copy: m = m.copy()

    components = (
        m[:-2,  1:-1],  # N
        m[2:,   1:-1],  # S
        m[1:-1, 2:],    # E
        m[1:-1, :-2],   # W
    )

    m[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.mean(np.stack(components), axis=0)
    return m

for _ in range(2):
    data = evolve_heat_slow(data)
    print(data)
```

Here, we define components by first taking the central 3x3 "window" and shifting it by 1 in each direction.  We then stack the shifted windows, take the mean, and replace the central window with those values.

After 1 iteration:

```
[[ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]
 [ 100.   50.   25.   50.  100.]
 [ 100.   25.    0.   25.  100.]
 [ 100.   50.   25.   50.  100.]
 [ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]]
```

After 2 iterations:

```
[[ 100.   100.   100.   100.   100. ]
 [ 100.    62.5   50.    62.5  100. ]
 [ 100.    50.    25.    50.   100. ]
 [ 100.    62.5   50.    62.5  100. ]
 [ 100.   100.   100.   100.   100. ]]
```